# Take a name value pair from one object and add it to a second

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript how can I take a name value pair from one object and add it to a second:

```
var myObj1 = {
  name : 'Jason',
  last : 'Rez'
};

var myObj2 = {};
```

I want `myObj2` to have the `'name : 'jason'` property.
edit..
Lets says I did not know which of the properties from myObj1 I wanted to add to myObj2, and I dont want them to share the mem location.

Comment: `myObj2.name = myObj1.name;`.

Comment: Or `var myObj2 = {name: myObj1.name};` ?? I have a feeling you're not asking about the actual problem at hand.

Comment: Well at some point you need to know the property. So are you talking about a generic function that can receive two objects (source and target) and a property name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**:

Re your edit

> Lets says I did not know which of the properties from myObj1 I wanted to add to myObj2, and I dont want them to share the mem

If you want to copy *all* of them, you can get their names via `Object.keys` or `for-in`:

```
Object.keys(myObj1).forEach(function(name) {
    myObj2[name] = myObj1[name];
});
```

or

```
var name;
for (name in myObj1) {
    if (myObj1.hasOwnProperty(name)) { // Remove if you want prototype props
        myObj2[name] = myObj1[name];
    }
}
```

---

**Original Answer**:

If you just want to create a property called `name` on `myObj2` with the value that `myObj1`'s `name` has *at that moment*, then it's just

```
myObj2.name = myObj1.name;
```

> I want myObj2 to have the 'name : 'jason' property.

If you want it to **share** the property with `myObj1`, it can't, really, but you can make it seem a lot like it does:

```
Object.definePropety(myObj2, "name", {
    get: function() {
        return myObj2.name;
    },
    set: function(newValue) {
        myObj2.name = newValue;
    }
});
```

That creates a propety on `myObj2` with *accessor methods* that access the property on `myObj1`.

Example:

```js
var myObj1 = {
  name: "Jason"
};
var myObj2 = {};
Object.defineProperty(myObj2, "name", {
  get: function() {
    return myObj1.name;
  },
  set: function(newValue) {
    myObj1.name = newValue;
  }
});
snippet.log("myObj1.name = " + myObj1.name);
snippet.log("myObj2.name = " + myObj2.name);
snippet.log("Setting myObj2.name = 'Freddy'");
myObj2.name = "Freddy";
snippet.log("myObj1.name = " + myObj1.name);
snippet.log("myObj2.name = " + myObj2.name);
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="//tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```